# Kotlin override generic variable

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following classes, but `myfield` variable in both `NumberField` and `TextField` cannot compile with:

Var-property type is InputField<String?>, which is not a type of overridden public abstract var inputField: InputField<*> defined in [my project]

```kotlin
interface FieldComponent {
    var myfield: InputField<*>  // <-- what should this be
}

interface InputField<T> {
    fun collectInput(): T
}

class NumberField(): FieldComponent{
    override lateinit var myfield: InputField<Int> // won't compile

    fun doSomething(){
        val x: Int = myfield.collectInput()
    }
}

class TextField(): FieldComponent{
    override lateinit var myfield: InputField<String> // won't compile

    fun doSomething(){
        val x: String = myfield.collectInput()
    }
}
```

I don't really need to know about the type in `FieldComponent`, but I need to have access to `myfield` if I have an instance of `FieldComponent`
Can we make this work? Thank you

Comment: `myfield` should be `val` in `FieldComponent`, otherwise you will not be able to use the subtypes when overriding the property

Comment: Why not use a type parameter like you did with the `InputField` interface?

Comment: Do you intend to let users of `FieldComponent` replace the value of `myfield`? I ask, because it was declared as `var`.

Comment: Changing `myfield` in `FieldComponent` to val solve the problem. Thank you all.

Comment: @IR42 consider converting your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted so that the question can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make `FieldComponent` generic.

```
interface FieldComponent<T> {
    var myfield: InputField<T>
}

interface InputField<T> {
    fun collectInput(): T
}

class NumberField(): FieldComponent<Int> {
    override lateinit var myfield: InputField<Int>
    fun doSomething(){
        val x: Int = myfield.collectInput()
    }
}

class TextField(): FieldComponent<String> {
    override lateinit var myfield: InputField<String>
    fun doSomething(){
        val x: String = myfield.collectInput()
    }
}
```